# discord.py How i make cogs in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i can't use cogs in discord.py. He gives me this error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
```

And when i make this:

```
await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
```

then gives me this error:

```
`SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`
```

Code:

```
for file in os.listdir(f"./cogs"):    
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
```

Thanks for help

Comment: By reading the docs that show how to do it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Try to put that code inside an async function.

```
async def your_function(...):
    for file in os.listdir(f"./cogs"):    
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
```

Comment: Does not work.. And which arguments in the function?

Answer (score 0):

So I have been struggling on this before, and I found the following solution after numerous trials.

I am not sure which version of discord.py you are using,
If you are **not** loading cogs for a **slash** bot using versions after discord.py **2.0** , just put your code inside an async function so that you can perform an await action. Like this:

```
async def preload():
for file in os.listdir(f"./cogs"):
  if file.endswith(".py"):
   await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
```

Make sure it is an **async** function.

Then call the function in the bot event `on_ready()` as you cannot call it outside a non-async function. Like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  await preload()
  print ('bot successfully logged in.')
```

It should work fine for message command bots.

If you hope for cog loading for a a **slash** bot using versions after discord.py **2.0**.

You have to done this in a class which succeed commands.Bot class. e.g.:

```
class abot(discord.commands.Bot):
  super().__init__(command_prefix = 'any ascii char', application_id = 0) #app_id = discord app id in int
```

Under this class there should be an async function called `setup_hook()`. (The function name has to be this)
The function is the one that sync all slash commands to your bot thru `tree` (tree is a property of the class) and you will have to load all cogs before syncing slash commands.
So `setup_hook()` should look like this:

```
async def setup_hook(self):
    for file in os.listdir("./cogs"):
      if file.endswith(".py"):
        await self.load_extension(f"cogs.{file[:-3]}")
    await self.tree.sync()
```

and event `on_ready()` is also under this class.
Note that the class only accepts events, but no commands.
Therefore for both `setup_hook` and `on_ready` functions you only have to directly `async def` the function, but **not** to add one more line to @ a property like `@bot.event`.

Hope this helps those struggle in cog loading.